# How to change only a part of web page? (is there a non JS solution?)

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, pyramid

Hi I'm pretty new to web applications, and I want to make a small form that search for an object and show the results there. I don't want to load the whole web page, probably change only one `<div>`  tag.

Is there a way to do this without Javascript? (It's not mandatory that I don't. Just checking if I can)

I'm using Pyramid framework (and has been working with less than 2-3 days, so please be patient with your answers).

Please point me in the right direction, I feel like I don't even know what to search for.

(Didn't go anywhere with my `pyramid XMLHTTPRequest` google search).

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's what AJAX *is*, a Javascript technique. You cannot initiate a XMLHTTPRequest from your browser without it.

Just use jQuery to load a URL from you Pyramid server; have one route serve up a HTML snippet instead of a full page:

```
$('div#somediv').load('http://serveraddress/route/to/snippet')
```

and jQuery will request `/route/to/snippet` from your server, and place the result wholesale under `<div id="somediv"></div>`.

Comment: Thx, any suggestions on where can find basics about pyramid+ajax?

Comment: @xcorat: There is nothing special about AJAX and Pyramid. *Any* AJAX tutorial will do.

Comment: @xcorat: The [Pyramid for humans tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/humans/index.html) includes an AJAX section.

Comment: awsome guys, that's actually what I needed, to know where to look (ajax tutorials it is) :)

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a Javascript library like jQuery to do the XMLHTTPRequest (popularly known as AJAX). See [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)